# yarn self-update throws OAuth2 Authentication error

Tags: npm, runtime-error, oauth-2.0, yarnpkg

I am trying out the `yarn self-update` command to see how it works, but instead of updating the Yarn version, it throws an OAuth error like so

```
yarn self-update
yarn self-update v0.15.1
error OAuth2 authentication requires a token or key & secret to be set
    at __dirname.authenticate (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/node_modules/github/lib/index.js:334:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli/commands/self-update.js:30:12)
    at next (native)
    at step (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
    at new Promise (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:191:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:12)
    at Object.run (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli/commands/self-update.js:99:17)
    at run (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli/index.js:237:18)
    at config.init.then (/Users/nikjohn/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli/index.js:345:12)
info Visit http://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/self-update for documentation about this command.
```

Does anybody know why this is and what needs to be done to resolve this? According to the docs [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/self-update), this command does not have any such OAuth dependency and IMHO it shouldn't either.

Looks like there's a PR for this already [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/676)

**Edit:** Further research shows this is a known [bug with Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/612). But a resolution is still not available. It would be a weird catch22 if the fix is pushed out as a new version, but users can't update because the command fails. One possible solution is `yarn self-update [tag]` instead of `yarn self-update`, but this remains a bug.*

**Edit:** I realized there's another workaround

```
yarn version
yarn version <version-number>
```

Comment: [yarn version](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version) is for updating the version in package.json not yarn itself.

Comment: No actually. If used without arguments, version can be used to update the yarn version

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/version

Comment: I just tried it again, but when used without argument you have the version of  the package displayed and a prompt that ask you to enter a new version.

Comment: Once the version question is answered package.json is updated with the new version. Try it you will see.

Comment: Additionally, when you try `yarn version` on a directory without package.json this message is displayed: `Couldn't find a package.json (or bower.json)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `npm -g install yarn` to update it. I got upgreaded to yarn v0.16.0 and now `yarn self-update` seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

First remove Yarn with this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.yarn
```

And then install it again, using this command (for example):

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Update to **`≥0.16.0`**:

**Ubuntu**

```
apt-get update ; apt-get install yarn
```

**MacOS**

```
brew update ; brew upgrade
```

**NPM**

```
npm install -g yarn --update
```

### Explanation

Had the issue on <s>`0.15.0`</s>, and looking into it lots of people add the same issue.

```
$ yarn --version
0.15.0
```

Reading the [release notes for `v0.16.0`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/tree/v0.16.0)

> Fix self-update ([#676](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/676))

So simply update :

```
yarn self-update
yarn self-update v0.16.0
success Yarn is already using the latest version.
Done in 0.69s.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm uninstall -g yarm 
npm cache clean
npm install -g yarm
```